# Procedure tr_EMPLOYEE2_FORINSERT, Line 10 Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server-2005-express

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_EMPLOYEE2_FORINSERT
ON EMPLOYEE2
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
--  SELECT * FROM INSERTED --INSERTED Table is a special table created for the purposes of Triggers, it is available only in the context of the trigger.
    DECLARE @ID INT
    SELECT @ID = ID FROM INSERTED

    INSERT INTO EMPAUDIT
    VALUES('New Employee with id = ' + cast(@id as nvarchar(5)) + ' is added at  ' + cast(getdate() as nvarchar(20)))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

a. We have no idea what your `EMPAUDIT` table looks like. But presuming it has more than one column (most tables do), you ought to use a column list for your [`INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) statement:

```
INSERT INTO EMPAUDIT (Column_To_Insert_Into)
VALUES('New Employee with id = ' + cast(@id as nvarchar(5)) +
       ' is added at  ' + cast(getdate() as nvarchar(20)))
```

b. However, the trigger it actually still broken. Why? Because [`inserted`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) can contain *multiple* rows (or no rows). So in fact what we want is:

```
INSERT INTO EMPAUDIT (Column_To_Insert_Into)
SELECT 'New Employee with id = ' + cast(i.id as nvarchar(5)) +
       ' is added at  ' + cast(getdate() as nvarchar(20))
FROM inserted i
```

and then you don't need the rest of the code you've written in your trigger